# What is the id for planted wheat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What's the id for planted wheat? I want to make a auto farm with command blocks!

Gonna drop a link on my profile !

Comment: This is one of the easiest things to find on the Minecraft wiki.  Please do at least some research before posting a question.

Answer (score 3):

The block ID for planted wheat is `minecraft:wheat`.

[You can see a full list of block IDs on the Minecraft Wiki.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Block_IDs) Alternatively, you can hover over the block and press <kbd>F3</kbd>, which displays the block ID to the right:

[image: Block ID in F3]